# SQL right join between tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables where I want to perform a join between them.

1st table looks like (named users)

```
id      column1
1       1
2       2
3       3
```

2nd table looks like (named transactions) here we have some transactions of users

```
user_id      transaction_date      transaction_expire
1            2017-03-31            2017-05-16
1            2017-02-28            2017-04-16
```

3rd table looks like (named user_logs) we have logs of the users based on days

```
user_id      date          some_log_data
1            2017-03-07    1505
1            2017-03-03    1201
1            2017-03-22    942
1            2017-03-31    1490
1            2017-04-05    1490
```

I want to know the sum of every user based on transactions something like:

```
user_id     transaction_date    transaction_expire    log
1           2017-03-31          2017-05-16            2980
1           2017-02-28          2017-04-16            6628
```

So this is the result which I want to achieve for every use get the SUM of their log in all transactions.

By doing this query between transaction_date and transaction_expire I get some result but when I try to do the summation the result are for all of them:

```
SELECT t.transaction_date, t.transaction_expire, ul.log
FROM user_logs as ul
    RIGHT JOIN transactions as t ON ul.user_id= t.user_id
WHERE ul.date BETWEEN t.transaction_date AND t.transaction_expire
```

This query gives me 7 rows which is correct but now I want to find only the sum of the logs in these two different transactions.

Comment: Are there any relations between the tables? For example I see no user_id column in the transactions table.

Comment: @jarlh Yes id is of other tables is the user_id so the join is going to be between the three tables knowing also for every user sum of logs in all transactions

Comment: The column names in the query don't match the ones in the sample data. Make some effort and make sure it's all consistent. Sample data and the expected result should match. Same names everywhere etc.

Comment: @jarlh I wanted to make it simpler the tables so I'm going to edit this query now.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is basically correct, but you need aggregation:

```
SELECT t.transaction_date, t.transaction_expire, SUM(ul.log)
FROM transactions t LEFT JOIN
     user_logs ul
     ON ul.user_id = t.user_id AND
        ul.date BETWEEN t.transaction_date AND t.transaction_expire
GROUP BY t.transaction_date, t.transaction_expire;
```

Also note that the condition in the `WHERE` clause is moved to the `ON` clause. I switched the `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`.  I find `LEFT JOIN` much more intuitive than `RIGHT JOIN`, because it keeps all rows in the *first* table.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.transaction_date, t.transaction_expire, SUM(IFNULL(ul.log, 0))
FROM user_logs as ul
    LEFT JOIN transactions as t ON (ul.user_id= t.user_id AND 
           ul.date BETWEEN t.transaction_date AND t.transaction_expire)
GROUP BY t.user_id, t.transaction_date, t.transaction_expire;
```

Your expected result contains user_id. So, I included that. If a user doesnt have a log, this will return a 0 for the SUM. I assume this is what you wanted